# How to find out what is currently selected? (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How to find out what is currently selected? (React-router-dom)

There is an **Auth.js** component that should output **SignUp** or **SignIn**. How to find out what is currently selected?

```
<div className="auth">
    <div className="auth__intro">
        <h1>Auth:</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="auth__form-intro">
        <SignIn /> // or <SignUp /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the registration form open when I click on "Register"?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvuQj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-router-dom`, you would use a `<Switch>` to display a different component based on the URL and `<Link>` elements to navigate between the routes. You can see an example [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) in their documentation on how to achieve this.